# how to control the order of evaluation in call by value?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I have some question about  call by value lambda calculus.

1)  λx.(λy.y)x is a stuck term or should be evaluated to λx.x?

2)  λx.(λy.y)(λz.z), what about this one?

3) how to control the order of evaluation in implementation?

I feel quite confused, could any one explain these value, stuck term, order of evaluation, how to control?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lamda calculus only defines how terms can be evaluated. Not what actually happens and in which sequence - that's left to the implementation, to choose an *evaluation strategy*. The point of pure functions is that it doesn't matter, you will always arrive at the same result.

Comment: @Bergi but different evaluation strategies can lead to different results...

Comment: @naomik not for pure functions, at least if you don't consider exceptions.

Comment: @Bergi, consider `(λx.z) ((λw.ww) (λw.ww))` – using normal order evaluation it results in `z`. But using applicative order it will never terminate.

Comment: @naomik right, that's what I meant by exceptions.

Comment: @Bergi understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) λx.(λy.y)x is a stuck term or should be evaluated to λx.x?

It can help to think in terms of terms and sub-terms. Here, we have:

- An abstraction, **λx.** (λy.y)x, with:

  - an application (λy.y)x, that applies

    - λy.y (an abstraction, with the simple term y) to
    - x.

Applications can be transformed, hence we get:

- An abstraction, **λx.** x, since the application rewrites to x. This is also written as the combinator **I**.

λx.(λy.y)x is *not* a stuck term: a term is stuck iff it cannot be transformed.

> 2) λx.(λy.y)(λz.z), what about this one?

Ideally, you now try to do this yourself.

We have:

- An abstraction, **λx.** (λy.y)(λz.z), with:

  - An application, that applies

    - The abstraction λy.y to
    - The abstraction λz.z.

We can transform the application using y=(λz.z) and get: λx.(λz.z), which can be shortened to λxz.z or **K***.

> 3) how to control the order of evaluation in implementation?

You can't. Lambda calculus does not define it. It is a computational model, not a programming language. Since lambda calculus is [confluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Normal_forms_and_confluence), any evaluation of a term will yield the same normal form *if it yields a normal form*. In other words, every term has at most one normal form, but infinite evaluation paths may exist.

The term KIΩ, for example, has an infinite reduction path since it reduces to itself (by reducing Ω ≡ ωω ≡ (λz.zz)(λz.zz) to itself), while it can also be reduced to I by applying K ≡ λxy.x.

Hence, the trick in a language based on lambda calculus is to choose an evaluation strategy that will yield a normal form if one exists. The most basic strategy is the ["leftmost outermost"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction_strategies) strategy, also called normal order evaluation, which always selects the leftmost λ abstraction that can be applied. It is inefficient, but guarantees to yield a normal form if one exists.

In programming languages, tricks have to been applied to make evaluation more efficient. Most commonly, this includes [strictness analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictness_analysis) and [graph rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_rewriting).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much clear now. Just one question,  we can further evaluate terms (1),(2) according to call by value, right?

Comment: I think the question is in the context of **call-by-value** lambda calculus. In that case, you do not reduce beta redex under lambda abstraction since it is already a value.